# Download .iso files faster

Tags: windows-7, iso-image, proxy-server

In my university, they have restricted the download speed for some file mime types such as (.mp3, .wmv, .avi, .flv, .iso) I wanted to download Visual Studio 2013 standalone .iso file. But I hate the slow. Are there any ways to boost the download. Are there any ways to changes the file extension and download.

Comment: Can you download it over HTTPS?

Comment: I'd look for a proxy service. If you know someone off-campus with a home internet connection, you could possibly even proxy through them. Squid is very popular http proxy software that could help. Or you could go talk to your admins and tell them you have work to do.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change the file extension of the download. You can use a proxy service however I would imagine the restriction is done on your network so that will not help - basically you will still be downloading ISO file but from a different destination.

So you got 2 options

1) try Microsoft's download manager - not only it uses CDN I also think it downloads as a different file until it is complete, than it changes it to ISO. For VS 2013 use this link
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40763

2) Download it as a zip from unofficial source

Comment: Are there any download managers which are faster and downloads as a different file until it is complete, than it changes it to ISO?

Comment: You have to get the other end to rename the file or use https.